# Как я могу добавить порт в исключение для VPN?

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, cloudflare

Я использую [WARP от CloudFlare](https://cloudflarewarp.com)

Он установлен на удаленной виртуальной машине Ubuntu 20.04. Я подключаюсь к виртуальной машине через SSH, порт 22.

Когда я включаю WARP ($warp-cli connect), ssh-соединение закрывается, и порт 22 становится недоступным.

Как я могу добавить порт 22 в исключение, чтобы WARP CloudFlare VPN не касался его?

Comment: Ну а заново через консоль открыть не получается?